# Objective-C Creating Dynamic Objects

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

After parsing a XML File,i want to create dynamic objects like `textbox` and buttons based on the contents of xml.
I have parsed my xml and retrieved the data.
I have created a seperate class for `XMLParser` and made the call in my `vieDidload` method.
Is it possible to call a method in my `mainViewController` class from my `XMLParser` class to create and the dynamic objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class which will read the parsed value and based on that you go on to create all the GUI Objects.That is not very difficult. Even you can add binding, connections, constraints etc. 
I actually did same thing while creating a framework for my project. I cant post the code as its copyright but I can share some of the hits. One basic hint I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

well... you can do it with a NSMutableDictionary.
OR you can fill objects that you modeled before from xml

---

basically just alloc init the existing object and set its properties:

example:

```
//parse xml
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
parser.delegate = (id<NSXMLParserDelegate>)self;
[parser parse];
```

e.g. company objects

```
//callback from parser
- (void)didStartFirmaWithParser:(NSXMLParser*)parser andAttributes:(NSDictionary*)dict {
[[self __didStartEntity:@"RLStoreFirma" withParser:parser] didStartFirmaWithParser:parser andAttributes:dict];
}

//general callback, sets the parsers delegate to THIS new object which then gets filled
- (id)__didStartEntity:(NSString*)name withParser:(AQXMLParser*)parser {
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[store.managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:name];
M42StoreEntry *entry = (id)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:store.managedObjectContext];

entry.store = self->store;
parser.delegate = entry;

return entry;
}
```

the object that is to be filled

```
#import "RLStoreFirma(info).h"

@implementation RLStoreFirma (info)
- (void)didStartFirmaWithParser:(AQXMLParser*)parser andAttributes:(NSDictionary*)dict {
}
-  (void)didEndFfkbWithParser:(AQXMLParser*)parser {
self.fkb = currentXMLCharacters;
}
-  (void)didEndFfirWithParser:(AQXMLParser*)parser {
self.name = currentXMLCharacters;
}
-  (void)didEndFirmaWithParser:(AQXMLParser*)parser {
if(!self.name) {
    self.name = self.fkb;
}
[self didEndMainWithParser:(AQXMLParser*)parser];
}
```

*generating new objects at runtime isnt allowed with the iphone sdk / its objc runtime*

---

```
#pragma mark parser magic

- (SEL) __startSelectorForElement: (NSString *) element
{
NSString * str = nil;
NSMutableString * eSel = [NSMutableString stringWithString: [[element substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)] uppercaseString]];

if ( [element length] > 1 )
{
    [eSel appendString: [element substringFromIndex: 1]];

    NSRange range = [eSel rangeOfString: @"-"];
    for ( ; range.location != NSNotFound; range = [eSel rangeOfString: @"-"] )
    {
        NSString * cap = [[eSel substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(range.location+1, 1)] uppercaseString];
        range.length += 1;
        [eSel replaceCharactersInRange: range withString: cap];
    }
}

str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"didStart%@WithParser:andAttributes:", eSel];

return ( NSSelectorFromString(str) );
}
```

syntactic sugar to make NSParser nicer.. I cant give you ALL code but I think this might help - i hope